# Du Meter Log file

Tags: windows-7, logging, bandwidth

Where can I find the Du Meter Log file? I tried searching `C:\ProgramData\Hagel Technologies\DU Meter` but the folder is empty.  I also tried `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming` and `Local` and `LocalLow` but none of them even have a Du Meter or Hagel Technologies folder.  I even tried searching the temp folder but still nothing.

I have a NetMeter.csv log file that I want to try and replace over the Du Meter log file cause I can't seem to find any other way to import data into Du Meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the chain of upgrades, e.g. version 3.x -> 4.x -> 5.x, the database file can end up in odd places. To find it for sure, do this:

- Open `RegEdit`, take a look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Hagel\DU Meter` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Hagel\DU Meter` (if you're using 64-bit Windows)
- Note the `DatabaseFile` value there. It points to current DU Meter dtabase file location. By default, it is in the `LocalSystem`'s profile, e.g. `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Hagel Technologies\DU Meter\DUMeter.sqb` or similar.

### Warning

DU Meter's data file is SQLite database. It is held open by DU Meter service, and if you want to backup it or otherwise tinker with it (not supported at all), stop the service first. I strongly advice you to leave this file alone. If you need to backup or restore your data, use "Database Management" in DU Meter options.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of DU Meter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, since I can import data from "Database Management" then searching for the db file doesn't matter (though I was still curious as to where it was).  I didn't expect it to be in the Windows folder (seems like a strange location to me)... but great program btw.  It is a lot more advanced than NetMeter that I was using previously.

Comment: Windows 7 x64: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Hagel Technologies

Answer (score 0):

Try `Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/Hagel Technologies/DU
Meter`.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7, I don't have that folder.

Comment: %APPDATA%/Hagel Technologies/DU Meter/

Comment: @Shiki  You know Windows uses \ don't you? looking at a windows path with / looks so wrong , doesn't it?

Comment: That's actually the same folder as `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming`... and Hagel or Du Meter doesn't exist.

Comment: @barlop - I just copied from JRobert's answer, but yeah, you are right... %APPDATA%\Hagel Technologies\DU Meter\